# Built in mics and mics on webcams not working

Tags: sound, microphone

As the title states, neither the built in mics nor the mics of multiple different webcams that I own work properly. They are all detected, but dont show any kind of change in the input level.

Rig Info: HP TouchSmart iq506 AIO

This problem started a month or so ago, and I've since installed many different distros. From every flavor of Ubuntu (minus Kylin an Studio), to Neon and MXLinux, and the problem has persisted across.

What makes this a head scratcher for me is, the fact that even the external USB webcam's mics don't work either. Although, they are detected via `lsusb` and they show up as input devices in Alsa and in Pulse.

I've tried muting, unmuting, setting as fallback and pretty much have clicked every single setting inside of Alsa and Pulse lol.

I've also tried the webcams on the other rigs that I have around here, and they work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if I can provide you any additional info, I'd be more than obliged to do so... just ask, as I'm not 100% sure what I should post.

Thanks for reading!

EDIT: Since I've posted this, none of my webcams (besides the integrated one) are even being detected when using `lsusb`. I can confirm that they do in fact still function properly, just not on this machine.

Comment: Did you check the mic volume in sound settings? I had a similar issue with the built-in mic and the problem was that the mic volume was set to 0.

Comment: yeah, I've tried all of the different settings in the Pulse mixer. I even tried changing some settings in the Alsa mixer too

Comment: Record a sample using the internal mic, then the external one. Does either of them sound like this? https://bit.ly/2XVVUzT

Comment: Man, I just now got the email for this. Thank you for commenting, I'll get right on it. brb

Comment: ok so I just tried to record with audacity, and not a peep played back upon running.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IptPuR0.png , https://pasteboard.co/IptPMfI.png

Those are the two screenshots of my current alsamixer configuration